# AngularJS view not updating after http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
angular.module('cmfApp').controller('InventoryAddCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', function($scope, $http, $timeout){

    $scope.submit = function() {
        var postData = {
            ihenterprise_logisticsbundle_stockItem: {
                name: $scope.formData.name,
                itemNo: $scope.formData.itemNo
            }
        }

        $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            url     : Routing.generate('ih_enterprise_api_stock_item_new'),
            data    : $.param(postData),  // pass in data as strings
            headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
        })
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.stockItems = $scope.stockItems.concat(data);
            //console.log($scope.stockItems); This logs with the new item
        }).error(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    };

}]);
```

The view is simply not updating when i concat to the scope array, if i try to call $scope.$apply(); after the concat, i get digest in progress, i have tried using setTimeout as well, does not help.

Here is the html(Twig):

```
{% block listTable %}
    <table class="table table-condensed table-expanding">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Created At</th>
            <th>Navn</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat-start="stockItem in stockItems" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#stockItem_{{ '{{stockItem.id}} '}}" class="accordion-toggle">
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
            </td>
            <td>{{ '{{stockItem.id}} '}}</td>
            <td>{{ '{{stockItem.created_at}} '}}</td>
            <td>{{ '{{stockItem.name}} '}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat-end="">
            <td colspan="6" class="hiddenRow">
                <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="package_{{ '{{stockItem.id}} '}}">
                    test
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

The controller InventoryAddCtrl is outside of the block, and initial data is applied correctly on page refresh.

Comment: I believe the issue is with button `type`, by default it is public, it should `type="button"` button will look like `<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
            </td>`

Comment: you need to use $apply

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('cmfApp').controller('InventoryAddCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', function($scope, $http, $timeout){

$scope.submit = function() {
    var postData = {
        ihenterprise_logisticsbundle_stockItem: {
            name: $scope.formData.name,
            itemNo: $scope.formData.itemNo
        }
    }

    $http({
        method  : 'POST',
        url     : Routing.generate('ih_enterprise_api_stock_item_new'),
        data    : $.param(postData),  // pass in data as strings
        headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
    })
    .success(function(data) {
 //You need to use $apply here.
   $timeout(function(){
       $scope.$apply(function(){      
        $scope.stockItems = $scope.stockItems.concat(data);
       });
      }); 
        //console.log($scope.stockItems); This logs with the new item
    }).error(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
};

}]);
```

Comment: I might be wrong in the syntax. Check for the documentation of using $apply.

Comment: I believe the syntax for `$apply` is correct, but, if it weren't, **you** as the answerer should check the syntax and post a syntactically correct answer as opposed to posting a syntactically incorrect answer and telling the asker to look up the syntax

Comment: Yes. I would have done that, if i got enough information. All i remember is to use $apply will solve the problem. And wish it should.

Comment: Not working i am afraid, getting this error:

Error: $rootScope:inprog
Action Already In Progress

Comment: setTimeout(function(){ scope.$apply(); }); Try this.

Comment: Dont use setTimeout. Its jquery. Use $timeout. and try.

Comment: It seems like the issue is more general i attempted to insert a normal item, not working.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure, but i think you have not define `$scope.stockItems` as empty array.

just put `$scope.stockItems=[];` just above `$scope.submit()` function